# how can I add to the score?

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop

I am pretty new to programming and am trying to get better. I have wrote this game in tkinter, but I can not figure out how can I add a while loop or something of that nature to my code so I do not have to reset the score to zero every time. I am also aware that my code is not the cleanest nor it is the best, but like I said I am pretty new to programming and was wondering if someone could help me figure out what should I do?

```
from tkinter import *
import random


m = Tk()
blank_space = " " * 65
m.title(blank_space + "Rock Paper Scissors Game")
m.config(width=600, height=400, bg='grey')


# Frames
button_frame = Frame(m, width=300, height=200)
button_frame.grid_propagate(False)
button_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=150)
text_frame = Frame(m, width=500, height=200)
text_frame.grid_propagate(False)
text_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=50)

# Functions


def rock():
    user_choice_label.config(text="your choice is : Rock")
    computer_score = 0
    user_score = 0
    user_choice = "Rock"
    available_text = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(available_text)
    if computer_choice == user_choice:
        computer_score = 0
        user_score = 0
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Paper":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score += 1
        user_score = 0
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Scissors":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        user_score += 1
        computer_score = 0
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")


def paper():
    user_choice_label.config(text="your choice is : Paper")
    user_score = 0
    computer_score = 0
    user_choice = "Paper"
    available_text = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(available_text)
    if computer_choice == user_choice:
        computer_score = 0
        user_score = 0
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Scissors":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score += 1
        user_score = 0
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Rock":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        user_score += 1
        computer_score = 0
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")


def scissors():
    user_choice_label.config(text="your choice is : Scissors")
    user_score = 0
    computer_score = 0
    user_choice = "Scissors"
    available_text = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(available_text)
    if computer_choice == user_choice:
        computer_score = 0
        user_score = 0
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Rock":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        computer_score += 1
        user_score = 0
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
    if computer_choice == "Paper":
        computer_choice_label.config(text=f"computer choice is : {computer_choice}")
        user_score += 1
        computer_score = 0
        user_score_label.config(text=f"your score is : {user_score}")
        computer_score_label.config(text=f"computer score is : {computer_score}")


# User Buttons
rock_button = Button(button_frame, text="Rock", activebackground='red', command=rock, width=15, bg='white')
rock_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=90, pady=15)

paper_button = Button(button_frame, text="Paper", command=paper, activebackground='red', width=15, bg='white')
paper_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=90, pady=15)

scissors_button = Button(button_frame, text="Scissors", command=scissors, activebackground='red', width=15, bg='white')
scissors_button.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=90, pady=15)

# Contents for the text frame
user_choice_label = Label(text_frame, text="your choice is : ")
user_choice_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

computer_choice_label = Label(text_frame, text="computer choice is : ")
computer_choice_label.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=120, pady=10)

computer_score_label = Label(text_frame, text="computer score is : ")
computer_score_label.grid(row=3, column=2)

user_score_label = Label(text_frame, text="your score is : ")
user_score_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20)

# Exit button
exit_button = Button(text_frame, text="Exit", command=m.destroy, width =30, activebackground='red')
exit_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3, pady= 20, padx=40)

m.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea to increment the scores is that you need to declare `user_score` and `computer_score` as a `global` variable.

```
global user_score, computer_score
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0

m = Tk()
blank_space = " " * 65

.....
.....
```

Also, in each function, add `global user_score, computer_score` and update the score assignment to increment (e.g. `computer_score += 0`).

For example,

```
def rock():
    global user_score, computer_score
    ....
    ....
    if computer_choice == user_choice:
        computer_score += 0
        user_score += 0
        ....
        ....
    if computer_choice == "Paper":
        computer_score += 1
        user_score += 0
        ....
        ....
    if computer_choice == "Scissors":
        user_score += 1
        computer_score += 0
        ....
        ....
```

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: awesome. thank you my friend.